# Time Series for Periods Over One Year

Tags: r, time-series

I'm having trouble doing time series for my data set. Most examples have quarterly or monthly frequencies but my issue comes with data that is collect annually or every two years. Consider my code:

```
data<-data.frame(year=seq(1978,2012,2), number=runif(18,100,500))
time<-ts(data$number, start=1978, frequency=.5)
decomp<-decompose(time)
Error in decompose(time) : time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

How do I make R recognize time series values from data that is collected over an annual basis? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seasonal decomposition only makes sense with intra-yearly data, because you have seasons within years. So, trying to calculate seasonal effects with `decompose` on data collected every two years you get the error.

Comment: Is there a workaround this? Should I falsely classify the time series to be collected in a year?

Comment: I think you need some cyclic models rather that seasonal.